# Similarities between "Walking in the Air" and "Royals"

Tags: similar-artists

[Walking in the air (youtube)](https://youtu.be/5A3THighARU?t=933)
[Royals - Lorde (youtube)](https://youtu.be/nlcIKh6sBtc?t=10)

These two melodies start off the same. How similar can two tunes be whilst remaining distinct from each other?

They are harmonized differently, but it's common practice when you reharmonize something not to say that it's a new tune - you instead acknowledge that it's a reharm.

So are they different or not?

And can anyone supply a prior art? Has this tune been "written" before by someone else?

[image: Walking vs Royals]

Comment: From the title alone I would close this due to opinion-basedness; the full text seems more to desribe a legal issue concerning copyright infingement than being well-founded in music.

Comment: The "Useless Song" from Kurt Weill's "Threepenny Opera" starts very similarly. https://youtu.be/-_PNVwIcuyA

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here --lots of songs have similarities --there's a limited number of notes after all. Do you want to know if one inspired the other? Or if there's an actionable copyright infringement? To understand what makes songs sound similar? Or just confirmation that other people hear what you hear?

Answer (score 0):

*Walking in the air* from *The Snowman* is the original, which was written in 1982 by [Howard Blake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Howard_Blake).

Nightwish made a cover of this song back in 1998 - [Nightwish - Walking in the Air](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8rRHX9bHik)

Answer (score -2):

I will submit this as an answer.

These two songs in no way resemble each other.  0.0%.

I will admit you have a similar vocalist, but none of the same chord progressions.  And there, you are lost.

Comment: The first melodic idea is almost identical in both songs (although certainly not original)